# Call instance method to updateValues based on file

Tags: java

I'm having trouble trying to get my program to have no error messages showing up in my IDE. The two problems I'm having is that I'm trying to read information from a file, use that information in an instance method to update the values (sum figures), and then later use a getter to return the totals. I'm having an error of "incompatible types, possible lossy conversion from double to char" in the while loop where I try to call my instance method updateValues. I'm getting " non-static method getTicketSalesIncome() cannot be referenced from a static context" when I try to use a getter to print the total. I have a feeling I need to do something like use the file object somehow but I am at a loss for how to correct that. I imagine there might be other problems with my code but those are the two main ones I need help with to move forward.

first file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class KingEventManager {   
    public static char getAmountType() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char amountType;    
    do {
        System.out.print("Enter the amount type (T, D, or E): ");
        amountType = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        amountType = Character.toUpperCase(amountType);        
        } while (amountType != 'T'||amountType != 'D' || amountType != 'E' );
        return amountType;
   }

   public static double getAmount() { 
       Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
       double amount;
       do { 
           System.out.print("Enter the amount value: ");
           amount = keyboard.nextDouble();
       } while (amount <= 0);
       return amount;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)  {
       System.out.println("This program reads data about expenses, ticket sales"
                        + ", and donations from a data file.");

       String fileName = "Event.txt";
       File file = new File(fileName);
       char amountType;
       double amount;     
       try {
            Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(file);      
            while (scanFile.hasNext() ) {           
                KingEventClass.updateValues(amount, amountType);
                amountType = scanFile.next().charAt(0);
                amount = scanFile.nextDouble();           
            }
            System.out.println("Total ticket sales : " +                         KingEventClass.getTicketSalesIncome() );
            scanFile.close();       
       } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.err.println("Failed to open file '" + fileName + ".");
       }
   }       
}
```

second file:

```
public class KingEventClass {   
    // data fields
    private double ticketSalesIncome;
    private double totalDonationAmount;
    private double totalEventExpenses;

    // object constructor
    public KingEventClass() {
         ticketSalesIncome = 0;
         totalDonationAmount = 0;
         totalEventExpenses = 0;
    }

    //accessors
    public double getTicketSalesIncome() {
        return ticketSalesIncome; 
    }
    public double getTotalDonationAmount() {
        return totalDonationAmount; 
    }
    public double getTotalEventExpenses() {
        return totalEventExpenses; 
    }


/**instance method
 * 
 * @param amountType
 * @param amount
 * @return 
 */
  public double updateValues(char amountType, double amount) {
        if (amount < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("*** The amount entered must be"
                                             + "greater than 0");
        }
        else if (amountType != 'T' || amountType != 'D' || amountType != 'E') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("**The amount type entered must"
                                             + "be 't', 'd', or 'e' ");
        }
        else { switch (amountType) {
                case 'T':
                    ticketSalesIncome = ticketSalesIncome + amount;
                    return ticketSalesIncome;
                case 'D':
                    totalDonationAmount = totalDonationAmount + amount;
                    return totalDonationAmount;
                default:
                    totalEventExpenses = totalEventExpenses + amount;
                    return totalEventExpenses;
            }        
        }
    }
    public void displayFinalResults() {
        double totalIncome = ticketSalesIncome + totalDonationAmount;
        double eventProfits = totalIncome - totalEventExpenses;
        System.out.println("Event Overall Outcome: ");
        System.out.printf("    Total Ticket Sales:   %.2f\n",
                          ticketSalesIncome);
        System.out.printf("    Total donations:      %.2f" + " +\n",
                          totalDonationAmount);
        System.out.println("                        --------");
        System.out.printf("    Total income:         %.2f\n", totalIncome);
        System.out.printf("    Total expenses:       %.2f\n", 
                          totalEventExpenses);
        System.out.println("                        --------");
        System.out.printf("Event profits:            %.2f\n", eventProfits);

    }        
}
```

Comment: `updateValues()` method is not defined as static but you are trying to access it as static : `KingEventClass.updateValues(amount, amountType);` and the same for `getTicketSalesIncome()`. You need to create an object of the class and then call these methods on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue I see is calling a non-static method from a static method. Your Java main is listed as a static (main methods must be static in Java, so we know we cannot change that.) The method updateValues() in KingEventClass is non-static. This means that when the Java main tries to call the updateValues() method, there is a chance it does not exist!

change

```
public double updateValues(char amountType, double amount)
```

to

```
public static double updateValues(char amountType, double amount)
```

Or create an instance of KingEventClass before calling updateValues within your while-loop.

```
KingEventClass kingEventClass = new KingEventClass();
kingEventClass.updateValues(your, values);
```

This will ensure the method exists when the Java main calls it.

As for you char to double issue... could you please describe which line specifically the error is occurring on?

::EDIT::
You lossy conversion issue is because you have mixed up the arguments in your method call. from your Java main, you pass in updateValues(double, char), but in your KingEventClass.updatevalues, Java is expecting (char, double). The order matters in this case, so just switch one of those around!

Comment: KingEventClass.updateValues(amount, amountType); is where it's happening at line 51

Comment: I've updated my answer with a solution to your "lossy conversion" problem

Comment: The `static` solution is bad. If you need to have access to the methods, you should have an instance of its class.

Comment: I agree the static solution is a bad one, because it would cause all the variables it accesses to be static as well. I much prefer the second solution of new'ing up the class.
I apologize, I should have noted that in my answer.